# Could a Ancient Rome-like civilization develop with vastly different geology?

Tags: alternate-history

If, for example, they developed in a region known for its foggy forests and open highlands, could an empire similar to the Roman Empire? And would their military style also develop similar or would heavy forests be adverse to that sort of thing? Would their cities look similar? Most likely they would be based in the highlands. Would there be a reason for it to look like the roman empire vs others? Or would that not matter? Thanks!

Comment: Which specific similarities are you after & what reasons do you think there may be problems developing those with this different geology? wine growing might be a problem in the environment you describe of course, but is wine consumption an important element of the society you're envisioning or irrelevant fluff?

Comment: Similar in what way?

Comment: Just checking: what are, in you opinion, the geological and climatic condition prevalent in Latium 2800 years ago? (Remember than Rome was once upon a time a small town, located in a what was to all purposes a swamp surrounded by forests, whose only immediately visible advantage was that it controlled a ford on the Tiber.) (Hint: why is a malaria named *mal aria*, and where did this name originate?) In other words, a geology "vastly different" *from what?*

Comment: Also, the Roman Empire extended over vast distances and wildly varying geology. From deserts to the arctic, ocean shores, mountains, lakes, rivers, vast forests, huge open planes, etc. and etc. So, how different do you want it to be?

Comment: not if the land can't support large scale agriculture.

Answer (score 5):

**What made Rome what it was?**

- **Luck and Momentum**
  Take a bunch of farmer and herder villages. One bunch of barely-organized militia conquers another. Then another. Perhaps it could have been the other way around. What was it why Rome came up on top and not Capua or Tarentum? A tiny initial advantage or pure luck?
- **Wise Laws**
  Was Rome better organized than their peer competitors? It is understood that the *rule of law* is important to economic success in the modern world. Were the [twelve tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Tables) a step in that direction?
- **Oil and Grain**
  Armies abroad depend on farmers at home. Can a foggy forest support them?

This last bullet point might get in the way of your example, unless the highlands can compensate. Do they have good soil and water? What about the climate at altitude?

Answer (score 2):

Too much of a general question but anyway.
Short answer. Yes. If they followed the correct methods of making an empire.

- Initial resources and abundance of materials is vital for the short term.
  But at a certain stage in every large states life comes a point where it is simply cheaper to import resource X that is cheap and available half way through the world than trying to farm the poor lands close by.
  Rome depending on Sicily and Egypt for grain for a famous example.
  In fact that is the hallmark of a strong state. 
  Trade, security, and stable roads allowing rapid movements of armies and safe travels of merchants.
  All the roads lead to Rome after all, and that is because they started from Rome.
- Stable political system. 
  Honestly I don't think I need to say much.
  During the republic they were adamant on the fact that no single man can rise to become a king. 
  Wanting to become a king was common insult and a way of warning people that a person was just amassing too much power.
  Obviously the republic became too corrupt to continue and that empire had it's troubles. But that is a whole different topic.
  Long story short: make a good stable political system.
- Practicality and flexibility. 
  Those barbarians are using a very effective weapon. 
  Lets copy them. Removing the land requirement to join the army means more soldiers, lets do it. We need one single leader to lead us in this time of crisis, lets select one.
  They had traditions and ideas and opinions and all. 
  But they were practical people who did what worked, they were also flexible enough to change time after time and not get bogged down in the mire of tradition.
  Though they probably would find convoluted methods of explaining how it is ok to invade Britain and Egypt. 
  But they were more of a: do the thing then find justification later type of people.
- Stubbornness.
  I swear to god Romans were insane.
  Hannibal annihilated every single army they sent against him.
  The guy was a legend. But what does Rome do?
  Send more armies until he was actually defeated. 
  I think that one of the greatest qualities of the Roman was just pure stubbornness.
- The perfect army. So much so that they got bored of conquering other nations and started fighting each other. That last part was more of a joke.
  But seriously thought. The Roman army after the Augustus reform was just too perfect to be defeated if put in the hands of a competent general. 
  Just a half way decent guy is enough.
- Stages of military evolution following defeat and humiliation. 
  I think this one is simple. 
  You just got wrecked by an army because your phalanx could not adapt to broken terrain, heavy infantry it is then. 
  Don't trust your Gallic allies? Put your soldiers on the horses.
  The enemy got elephants? Just make lanes in your formation for the elephants to pass through while you shot at them...etc. 
  You can't just have a fighting style out of nowhere. 
  Trial and error is the name of the game.
- Every empire exists despite nature and obstacles. That is what an empire means.
  So unless the starting location is too hostile to actually support the people then you should be fine.
  But you have to explain stuff. 
  I think this might be the real answer.
  The Chinese, Japanese, Persians, Egyptians...etc all had large stable states at different time and had to compete with harsh natural and human elements.
  So I don't think your empire won't rise if it had the will power.
- A long time.
  So Rome took it's time ruling the world. Gaul was added when Caesar decided to take the place and Egypt was finally a province shortly after.
  So the famous borders of Trajan was not built in a day, no pun intended. 
  It took something like 600 years to reach that point.